# Configuración de llaves - Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Estoy utilizando la extensión `PHP Formatter` y para ordenar el código utilizo Shift + Alt + F el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que yo necesito es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que las llaves de mi código no realicen un salto de linea, cuando ejecuto el ordenamiento automatico de `PHP Formatter`?

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes editar la configuración de las transformaciones de la extensión **PHP Formatter** a través de:

> Archivo > Preferencias > **Ajustes**

El estilo que quieres cambiar se denomina Allman, y la denominación en la extensión es **AllmanStyleBraces**.

Curiosamente, existen **más métodos** de escritura aparte de Allman:

[image: Métodos de escritura]

Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt) respecto a las preferencias que quieres cambiar, aparte de **AllmanStyleBraces** en PHP Formatter.

En [otra área de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line) también tuvieron el mismo problema, pero al contrario.

Comment: Gracias @ortizlab !

Answer (score 3):

Si la extensión es la que pienso, php-formatter de *sophisticode*, viendo la descripción:

> A wrapper for the Sensiolabs PHP CS Fixer. Analyzes some PHP source
>   code and tries to fix coding standards issues (PSR-1 and PSR-2
>   compatible).

te dire que la llave en la siguiente línea a la de la declaración para un método / función PHP es una de las especificaciones del standard PSR-2, que suele aplicarse por defecto.

Debes cambiar las "normas" que aplica la herramienta si no quieres usarlas. La página con las instrucciones de configuración es la siguiente: https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter/wiki/Configuration. Para el uso que quieres, deberás crear un [fichero de configuración](https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter/wiki/Configuration#custom-config-file) en el que se especifican las [reglas que se van a aplicar](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:2.15), selecciona las que necesitas del listado.

El fichero de configuración que viene como ejemplo es este:

```
<?php

$finder = Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::create()
    ->files()
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->exclude('vendor')
    ->exclude('resources/views')
    ->exclude('storage')
    ->exclude('public')
    ->notName("*.txt")
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreVCS(true);

$fixers = [
    '-psr0',
    '-php_closing_tag',
    'blankline_after_open_tag',
    'double_arrow_multiline_whitespaces',
    'duplicate_semicolon',
    'empty_return',
    'extra_empty_lines',
    'include',
    'join_function',
    'list_commas',
    'multiline_array_trailing_comma',
    'namespace_no_leading_whitespace',
    'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening',
    'no_empty_lines_after_phpdocs',
    'object_operator',
    'operators_spaces',
    'phpdoc_indent',
    'phpdoc_no_access',
    'phpdoc_no_package',
    'phpdoc_scalar',
    'phpdoc_short_description',
    'phpdoc_to_comment',
    'phpdoc_trim',
    'phpdoc_type_to_var',
    'phpdoc_var_without_name',
    'remove_leading_slash_use',
    'remove_lines_between_uses',
    'return',
    'self_accessor',
    'single_array_no_trailing_comma',
    'single_blank_line_before_namespace',
    'single_quote',
    'spaces_before_semicolon',
    'spaces_cast',
    'standardize_not_equal',
    'ternary_spaces',
    'trim_array_spaces',
    'no_useless_else',
    'unalign_equals',
    'unary_operators_spaces',
    'whitespacy_lines',
    'multiline_spaces_before_semicolon',
    'short_array_syntax',
    'short_echo_tag',
    'concat_with_spaces',
    'ordered_use',
];

return Symfony\CS\Config\Config::create()
    ->level(Symfony\CS\FixerInterface::PSR2_LEVEL)
    ->fixers($fixers)
    ->finder($finder)
    ->setUsingCache(true);
```

Deberías comenzar con el fichero lo más completo posible y descartar las que no quieras usar. La *norma* lleva a cabo el comportamiento que quieres evitar es esta: ***braces***, entonces, **no hay que añadirla a la lista de reglas**.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he llegado a éste artículo buscando lo contrario, el volver a tener las líneas de separación entre llaves. No sé como se me cambiaron, seguramente con alguna instalación de alguna extensión de VSCode.
Respondo por si más gente llega a éste post buscando lo mismo que yo buscaba.[image: La imagen muestra la palabra y la casilla que modificar para establecer las abrazaderas con líneas de separación]