# ¿Cómo configuro VSCode para poner llaves con el estilo Allman en lineas separadas como C # pero en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, dart, vscode

por ejemplo si escribo un bloque de codigo de este modo

```
if (edad < 18)
{
    print('Eres menor');
}
```

Si como el formato de C# asi es que la quiero
PERO
Si escribo un codigo en JavaScript, VSCode Me lo formatea asi:

```
if (edad < 18){
    alert('Eres menor');
}
```

Incluso Si lo escribo en Dart, VSCode Lo formatea automáticamente también así:

```
if (edad < 18){
    print('Eres menor');
}
```

Como puedo hacer que automáticamente cada vez que escriba una función o un método o un bloque de ccodigo como el if else, como hago que el vs code me formatee automáticamente al estilo Allman como mostré en el primer bloque de arriba, (Esto para cualquier lenguaje de programación que utilice )

Comment: @Junior no hay que ponerle tensión a los comentarios, se te hizo una observación que ya corregiste y eso ayudará a que la pregunta tenga mejor recibimiento; dado eso no debemos molestarnos, te recomiendo la lectura del [tour]; ahora solo toca esperar la eventual respuesta

Comment: Revisa el IntelliJs a ver posiblemente debe estar una configuracion que te permite arreglar eso

Answer (score 0):

Podes cambiarlo en **File\Preferences\Settings** y buscar `brace`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Tendrías que ver la opción que te da el formatter que tenes instalado, y si tenes más de uno instalado, ver que no se pisen.*

---

Para formatear el archivo tenes dos opciones:

1. Click derecho dentro del archivo, sobre el código.
2. Con el atajo:

- Windows: Alt + Shift + F
- Linux: Ctrl + Shift + I
- macOS: ⌥ + ⇧ + F

---

[Acá podes ver otras respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line), o [ver el caso contrario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266276/configuraci%C3%B3n-de-llaves-visual-studio-code?rq=1), para `php`.